# Rails - Don't have access to instance variable in form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm pretty new to rails and am working on an online store, just to write some rails. I have a review form and need a hidden field to pass the product id. For some reason I can't access the 'product' instance variable in the form.

**The Form:**

```
<%= form_for @comment, remote: true do |f|   %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.label :comment %>
  <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  <%= f.label :rating %>
  <%= f.text_field :rating, value: 5 %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, :value => @product.id %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I'm rendering the form with a new.js.erb file:

```
$('#comment-form').html("<%= j (render 'layouts/review_form') %>");
$('#comment-form').slideDown(350);
```

And this is the trigger-link and the div:

```
<%= link_to 'Write a review', new_comment_path, remote: true %>
<div id="comment-form" style="display:none;"></div>
```

When i get rid of the the hidden_field everything works like its supposed too. Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you tell us what error you're getting when the hidden_field line is present? Could you also add to this questions the action (in the controller) which causes the form to render? Thanks!

Comment: This is the error: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
My controller only contains index, new and create methods, nothing else

Comment: So this is presumably the result of the New action, correct? In which case you need to confirm that the New action defines product (the reason it's giving you that error is that product hasn't been defined for the action that corresponds to this view).

Comment: there would be associations between product and comments. so could you add those in your question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails, an instance variable is available in a View only when defined in the action which renders that view. For instance, if we are looking at the comments/new.html.erb file right now, you would need to define both @comment and @product in comments_controller.rb's "new" action. So right now, presumably your action looks something like this:

```
def new
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

To access @product now, you must have a way of identifying *which* product is @product. I don't know how you intend to do this, but if we imagine that product_id is a parameter, this would work.

```
def new
  @comment = Comment.new
  @product = Product.find( params[:product_id] )
end
```

I have to imagine you don't have that parameter in place yet, but this is essentially what must be done in the controller.

The other option in *some* scenarios would be to use a relationship between @comment and @product to access @comment.product.id in the View, but that will not work in this scenario as you are defining a new Comment which does not already contain a reference to the Product, presumably.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot! Greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @Paul You're quite welcome! If you need further help learning how to pass/access parameters in the controller, don't hesitate to ask. That said, this may prove to be a useful resource for you:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters

Comment: Thank you. Will look into it

Answer (score 1):

To add to `@ConnorCMcKee`'s answer, you'll want to use a [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) instead of setting a hidden field. I try to steer clear of hidden fields as much as possible (too easy to manipulate).

You'd be better with:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :products do
   resources :comments #-> url.com/products/:product_id/comments/new
end
```

This sets the `params[:product_id]` variable through your routes, not the form. It might not seem as secure, but to be gives a more semantic appeal:

```
<%= link_to 'Write a review', new_product_comment_path(@product), remote: true %>
```

Everything else should work as is (with `@ConnorcMcKee's` answer)

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into that.